# How to automatically change wallpaper after every 30 seconds using JobScheduler?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-jobscheduler, android-wallpaper, jobservice

I am creating application where there is an option of checkbox allowing user to change wallpaper automatically after 30 seconds. I am using JobScheduler and have passed arraylist of images by serializing them to JsonArray and then to String and passed it using PersistanceBundle:

```
JsonArray result = (JsonArray) new Gson().toJsonTree(wallpaperModelArrayList,
                        new TypeToken<List<WallpaperModel>>() {
                        }.getType());
PersistableBundle persistableBundle=new PersistableBundle();
persistableBundle.putString("wallpaper",result.toString());
mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
                        getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                        new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                                JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
                builder.setExtras(persistableBundle);
                builder.setPeriodic(30000);
```

And my JobService class:

```
public class JobSchedulerService extends JobService {

private static final String TAG = "JobSchedulerService";
private String images;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartJob:");
    images = params.getExtras().getString("wallpaper");
    changeWallpaper(params);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    //Log.i(TAG, "onStopJob:");
    return true;
}

private void changeWallpaper(JobParameters params) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<WallpaperModel>>(){}.getType();
    List<WallpaperModel> list = gson.fromJson(images, listType);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(list.get(0).getUrlImage())
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super
                        Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    try {
                        WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
    jobFinished(params, false);
}

}
```

I don't know how to set wallpaper(images one by one) after every 30 secs out of the list I have in JobService?Can Anyone tell me how setperiodic function works(what happens after 30secs)? This approach can be wrong. Can anyone guide me on how to do this? Thanks in advance.